# Can mongoose return a document or only one of its fields in one query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a set of documents that get rendered into a visual representation as an SVG.

Currently, the rendering happens client-side using D3, after the client requests the document from the server.

Since the data is inherently a snapshot, it is immutable, and a server-side rendering would save a lot of time and resources on the client-side.

Is there a way to store the rendering in MongoDB so that I can use one query to either return the unrendered document, or its rendering, but not both, to the client? Based on the data the client receives it then can decide to render it, or simply insert the rendering into the HTML DOM?

An alternative could be to query for the rendering, and in case of no result, to render, store it, and then pass on the rendering to the client?

A second alternative might be to introduce a state to the documents, where the transition to a "published" state would trigger the rendering to be stored, and (anonymous) clients only able to query published documents?

TIA!

**UPDATE: Example added as requested.**

Suppose the Mongoose schema is as follows (abbreviated for clarity):

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    year: Number,
    release: String,
    name: String,
    rendering: String // this is the field to hold the rendered version
})
```

The data that is to be rendered is mostly stored in other documents that are pulled in when the rendering is to happen in a business logic function in Express, and then sent off to the client for rendering. The field "rendering" is supposed to be empty/null when there is no pre-rendered visualisation (I exploit the scaling capabilities of SVG in the HTML/CSS layout on the client to be independent from endpoint screen sizes)

An unrendered example would be sent to the client as a JSON message using a JSEND format (quotes omitted for readability):

```
{
    status: success,
    type: raw
    data: {
        _id: ...
        year: 2020
        release: A release name
        name: Example data
    }
}
```

However, if a rendering exists, then the JSON message would look like this:

```
{
    status: success,
    type: svg
    data: {
        _id: ...
        rendering: <svg>...</svg>
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the Mongoose query (or MongoDB) to accomplish this in one query, as this would be executed every time a client would request to see the respective rendering on screen - that would halve the number of queries, lowering the load on the DB.

As I said, I am open to suggested alternative solutions; see the original post for some ideas.

Comment: Could you show any example of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi @mickl, thanks for responding; I updated the original post.